# Vagrant add box via ssh

Tags: vagrant

I have a vagrant box that I want to add from an SSH address.  The docs say you can give an http or https URL.

How do I add something like:

`vagrant add box https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64`

using ssh instead.  This **does not** work:

`vagrant add box ssh://host:/path/to/box --name test/box1`

How can I pull the box via ssh instead of http/https, since I don't want people to have to pull it locally manually?

Comment: So what is your question for Stack Overflow? This looks more like a feature request or bug report for vagrant.

Comment: copy the box file locally and add it from there

Comment: I edited to add the implied question, which is how do I pull it via ssh?  I don't want to require people to copy the box locally, just install Vagrant, check out the Vagrant file and do 'vagrant up'